# Make WMP sort by title by default / on startup

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player, music

Windows 10 and WMP 12 here.

I memorize, organize and match my songs by name, so I've set all my media players to sort by song title by default. Now I'm stuck with Media Player. It always sorts by album name by default. I have to tell it to sort by title every time I launch WMP.

Is there any way to set a default sorting in WMP?

Answer (score 0):

In which of WMP's views are you where it sorts by album name by default? WMP's most commonly used `Music` view sorts by album **artist**, not album name.

There isn't any view in WMP that sorts by title, but you could create an Auto Playlist that provides such sort order. In WMP's library, click the arrow next to `Create playlist` and select `Create auto playlist`. Enter a name for the playlist, and under `Music in my library`, add the condition `Sort By`, then further customize the condition so that it reads `Sort by Title Ascending order`. Click `OK` to create the auto playlist.